# When iframes are in loading state, the main page seem to be broken while scrolling through it on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iframe

My code is simple and it simply puts 5 iframes within cards (as can be seen below) one after another. When they are in loading state, the page seems to be broken and nothing is visible (as you can see below that the second card is only half visible) after first or second iframe until all of them are loaded. I tried to hide them using `display:none` only to be displayed when the loading was complete (using `onload` event). But, the result was same.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, if you provide some code, it would be easier to identify the problem

Comment: There's no need to provide any code in this case. It's more of a device issue. I wanted to know if there was any workaround to it.